# add parameter in current url in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

how to add parameter in current url in cakephp ?

exemple
current url :

```
http://localhost/testwebsite/posts/index/Search.brand_id:1
```

I want add parameter and do a link

```
http://localhost/testwebsite/posts/index/Search.brand_id:1/Search.shop_id:1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create URL like:

```
echo $this->Html->link('View Page', array(
    'controller' => 'page',
    'action' => 'view',
    '?' => array('Search.brand_id' => 1, 'Search.shop_id' => 1))
);
```

which will create link like [View Page](/page/view/?Search.brand_id=1&Search.shop_id=1)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
$this->request->query();
```

**Example :**

```
// url array
array('ext' => 'json', '?' => array('foo' => 'bar')

// resulting url
/controller/action.json?foo=bar

$foo = $this->request->query('foo');
// returns "bar" in our example - or null if no foo key is found
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like below. and get parameter on your function.

```
$data = $this->params['url'];
```

http://localhost/testwebsite/posts/index?brand_id=1&shop_id=1